# Axios POST is not parsed correctly in Python Flask

Tags: python-3.x, vue.js, flask, axios, flask-cors

### Intro

Hi, I can see this question asked multiple times, but not a proper solution.

### whats wrong

GET requests are working as expected. but if I use Vue.js and Axios to send a POST request to a flask server.

POST with JSON sent with Postman also works..

heres the axios call:

```
async submit() {
      await this.$axios.post("/bob/posting", { foo: "bar" }).then(response => {
        console.log(response)
      })
}
```

On the flask side:

```
from flask import Flask, request
from flask_cors import CORS,cross_origin
app = Flask(__name__)
cors = CORS(app, resources={r"//*": {"origins": "*"}})

@app.route('/bob/posting', methods=['POST'])
def handleRoute():
    print(request.is_json)
    return (
        request.args
        or request.form
        or request.get_json(force=True, silent=True)
        or request.data
    )
```

The results at the flask side:

True will be printed (indicating a json request)

nothing will be returned (also, for each option I tried printing it individually just in case)

### Q

How can I properly use variables received from an axios json request on a flask server?

Comment: Was there any error in POST for your request? Should be red-lined in Chrome Inspector > Network to your API. or using Postman to see what's wrong (whether from your Flask or Vue side)

Comment: no error, just hangs instead of printing the json and then flask returns 400

Answer (score 0):

Did not at all understand why, but adding a text/plain content type fixed it.. what...

```
async submit() {
      await this.$axios.post("/bob/posting", { foo: "bar" }, {'content-type':'text/plain'}).then(response => {
        console.log(response)
      })
}
```